# Referencing filtered Schema object into another using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to filter the data and reference it to another schema. I am not sure what is the right way, but I am trying this and its inserting nothing.

```js
let hyp = Hypothesis.findOne({ name: "test-hyp" }).then(function(doc) {
  return doc._id;
});

var comp = {
  hypothesis: hyp,
  compName: "test",
  created_at: new Date()
};

var h2h = new Comparison(comp);

h2h.save(function(error) {
  if (!error) {
    Comparison.find({ _id: h2h._id })
      .populate("hypothesis")
      .exec(function(error, comps) {
        console.log("insertion done ");
      });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using the wrong approach for referencing schema

```
Hypothesis.findOne({name:"test-hyp"}, function(err,doc) {
    var comp1 = new Comparison({
        hypothesis_1: doc,
        created_at: new Date()
    });

    comp1.save(function (err, ret) {
        console.log("err: ", err);
   });
});
```